# Python 3 - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have this wrong code and can't find the fix.

```
49         os.system('powershell -enc 
    '+base64.b64encode(addpermissions.encode('utf_16_le')))   
    . 
    .
    .
     137 HexRegHash, HexRegSysk, jd, skew1, gbg, data = getRegistryValues(HexRID)
```

I have this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "hash.py", line 137, in <module>
        HexRegHash, HexRegSysk, jd, skew1, gbg, data = 
    getRegistryValues(HexRID)
      File "hash.py", line 49, in getRegistryValues
        os.system('powershell -enc 
    '+base64.b64encode(addpermissions.encode('utf_16_le')))
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`base64.b64encode` produces a byte-stream, not a string. So for your concatenation to work, you have to convert it into a string first with `str(base64.b64encode(addpermissions.encode('utf_16_le')))`

```
b64cmd = base64.b64encode(cmd.encode('utf_16_le')).decode('utf-8')
os.system('powershell -enc ' + b64cmd)
```

EDIT: Normal string conversion didn't work with os.system, used `decode('utf-8')` instead

Comment: It produce an error like this:
The command could not be processed. The value specified with -EncodedCommand is not correctly encoded. For the value it is necessary to use Base64 encoding.

Comment: Looks like `os.system` has a problem with the result. Instead of calling the str constructor, you have to explicitly convert it to an utf8 string. `base64.b64encode(addpermissions.encode('utf_16_le')).decode('utf-8')`. I've updated my original post

Comment: `str()` without a specified encoding just returns the result of an object's `__str__` (or otherwise `__repr__`) method, which for a `bytes` object is its repr (e.g. `"b'spam'"`). The result from `b64encode` can be decoded as `'ascii'`, though UTF-8 works because it extends ASCII.